# How to make a button click a button on a different page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button on one html page, but when clicked I want it to activate a different button on a different html page. Is this possible?

Comment: Only in the some domain and when one of the pages is opened from the other.

Comment: Can a click event fire a click event in a separate browser tab? No. This is by design to prevent malicious behavior (hacking).

Comment: Can you put own JavaScript on the second page?

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible if the first page actually generates the second page (via `window.open()`). Otherwise, you won't have any way to access the document in the other window.

Here's an example:

```
var newWin = window.open("other page in my domain");
var otherButton = newWin.document.querySelector("selector to find button");
otherButton.click();
```

Comment: This is the case. The first button links to the second page, and I want clicking the first button to also click a button on the second page.

Comment: @Ebower No, linking to another page is not what I'm saying and will not work. The first page must programmatically cause the second window to be created with the second page inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work though, but it requires passing a value from one page to another. It cannot link pages together. If you want that look into [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/WebSockets).

Page 1

HTML

```
<button id="activate">Activate other page</button>
```

JavaScript

```
document.querySelector("#activate").addEventListener("click", function(){
    location.href = "page2.html?button=activate"; //mind the querystring here.
});
```

Page 2

HTML

```
<button id="toactivate" disabled>disabled button</button>
```

JavaScript

```
var activateButton = location.search.slice(1); //querystring | get rid of the ?
activateButton.split(/&/);
activateButton.forEach(function(value){
    var splitted = value.split("=");
    if (splitted[0] == "button" && splitted[1] == "activate")
    {
       document.querySelector("#toactivate").removeAttribute("disabled");
    } 
});
```